# General method to fit a number into a sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence

The general problem is as follows. Given an increasing sequence of positive integers `0 < s_1 < s_2 < s_3 < ...` and a positive integer `n`, is there an efficient algorithm to find the (unique) index `k` such that `s_k <= n < s_(k+1)`?

A concrete example of this problem with a particular nice solution is to find the largest nonzero digit of a binary expansion, i.e. take `s_i = 2^(i-1)`, and then `k = log_2(n)`.

A slightly harder example is to find the largest nonzero digit in the factorial expansion, i.e. take `s_i = i!`.

The example that I have in mind that brings up this question is the following:

`s_i` = `i`th triangular number = `1 + 2 + ... + i` = `i(i+1)/2`

I'd like a nice solution to this, meaning something better than the following

```
for(int i=1; ; ++i) {
  if (triangle[i] > n)
    break;
}
return i;
```

**NOTE**: One cannot use a binary search here since the sequence is *infinite*. Of course, there is the obvious constraint that `k <= n`, but this is a horrible bound in general. For example, if `s_i = i!`, then using a binary search on `n=20` requires computing `20!` when the answer is `k=3`, so one shouldn't need to compute beyond `4!`.

Comment: You could try a binary search instead, it is normally faster

Comment: @Nico No, you can't. The sequence is infinite.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't noticed that :)

Comment: Also, this doesn't sound "like a practical problem that you're actually facing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach: Try solving the equation `n = s(x)` and the set `k = floor(x)`.

For `s_i=2^(i-1)` you get `x=log2(n)+1`. For `s_i=i*(i+1)/2` you get `x=(sqrt(1+8n)-1)/2`.

In case that the equation is not solvable analytically, try an approximation (e.g. [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)), or simply use a binary search on the sequence.

Comment: Once cannot use a binary search on an infinite sequence

Comment: @PengOne: Sort of binary search. You can start from index 1 and jump in factors of 2. Then you apply standard binary search on a bounded segment. This limits your steps count to be proportional to log(n), where n is the number you are looking for.

Comment: the idea of jumping by factors of `2` is somewhat arbitrary. Try this with the sequence `s_i = i!`. In general, this assumes the sequence grows exponentially at worst, which is a poor assumption.

Comment: Thanks for solving the triangular numbers problem, but this still begs the question of what to do in general.

Comment: @PengOne: No, there's no assumption here, and the bound O(log n) still holds. To cross the value n in the sequence you need log2 n steps, and then you are left with a candidate range containing at most 2n items. You can now apply standard binary search on this range, which also costs O(log(n)).

Comment: If the sequence grows much faster or much slower than exponential, then "jump by 2" is not a good approach.

Comment: @PengOne: Why not? remember that the jump is on the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68447/discussion-between-pengone-and-eyal-schneider).

Comment: @PengOne: for a growth slower than exponential, jumps by 2 is an excellent strategy (probably optimal). For the case of factorials, it is also quite acceptable, with a log-linear O(i.Lg(i)) behavior. For superexponential growth, the real challenge is probably storage/representation of the numbers rather than efficient search.